# Renaming an image created from an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, filenames, html5-canvas, data-url

I have made a simple canvas and save it as an image. I have done this with the help of this code:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
 var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

and pop up the created image with this:

```
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

But its name is always a weird one. I want to rename the image name like `faizan.jpg` etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723931/javascript-previews-with-new-filereader-api-and-dataurls-seem-inefficient/6723973#6723973.

Comment: short answer is "its impossible" in current browsers. long is "upload that image to a server, store it there, and give user url to it"

Answer (score 3):

To put it simply, you can't. When you call the toDataURL method on an HTMLCanvasElement it generates a string representation of the image as a Data URL. Thus if you try to save the image, the browser gives it a default filename (e.g. Opera saves it as default.png if the Data URL was a png file).

Many workarounds exist. The simplest one is to make an AJAX call to a server, save the image on the server-side and return the URL of the saved image which can then be accessed and saved on the client-side:

```
function saveDataURL(canvas) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            window.location.href = request.responseText;
        }
    };
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.open("POST", "saveDataURL.php", true);
    request.send("dataURL=" + canvas.toDataURL());
}
```

To save the image on the server side, use the following PHP script:

```
$dataURL = $_POST["dataURL"];
$encodedData = explode(',', $dataURL)[1];
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
file_put_contents("images/faizan.png", $decodedData);
echo "http://example.com/images/faizan.png";
```

Comment: can u kindly explain  where the code is changing the image name , and where the image is being saved on the server side ?

Comment: I'm assuming you know a little bit about server-side scripts. The saveDataURL function sends the image to the server in the form of a Data URL. Then the server simply reads it, decodes it and saves it in a file (with a custom name) and returns the URL of that file to the client. Then, in the onreadystatechange function the image with the changed name is loaded.

Comment: i have not done any server side scripting with ajax before. thats y i am asking , which of these line is renaming the image file name ?           request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.open("POST", "saveDataURL.php", true);
    request.send("dataURL=" + canvas.toDataURL());

Comment: None of them. The renaming is done on the server side and I've added the PHP script which does that.

Comment: its not working :( . i have put the php code in saveDataURL.php

Comment: You'll need a web server. PHP is a server-side script. Install Apache, PHP and MySQL on your computer. See the following [link](http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/apache) for instructions.

Comment: i have xampp on my system ,and using localhost to access the page and save image !

Comment: What error does it give? The PHP code I provided is not tested. Try alerting the responseText in html. It'll probably give you an error message with a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Got this working 100%! Just had to do a little debugging to the above answer. Here's the working code:

The JavaScript:

```
var saveDataURL = function(canvas) {
  var dataURL = document.getElementById(canvas).toDataURL();
  var params = "dataURL=" + encodeURIComponent(dataURL);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/save-data-url.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  window.console.log(dataURL);    

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      window.console.log(request.responseText);
    }
  };

  request.send(params);
}
```

/scripts/save-data-url.php:

```
<?php
  $dataURL = $_POST["dataURL"];
  $encodedData = explode(',', $dataURL);
  $encodedData = $encodedData[1];
  $decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
  file_put_contents("images/log.txt", $encodedData);
  file_put_contents("images/test.png", $decodedData);
  echo "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/test.png";
?>
```