# Send Dynamically generated Image in Javascript as Image Header in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, image, http-headers, mime

> **What I am doing**

**Generating a dynamic image via javascript** based on some variables specified in the query string. I am using this **in a PHP Website**.

> **What I need**

The point here is **I want to send this dynamically generated image** in javascript to be displayed on the page **as Image Header**.

> **What I am using**

PHP with APACHE Server **(wamp)**

> **Similar example of what I require**

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World

This is a Google Chart API, **upon hitting the above URL, it returns you a PNG image** based on the parameters specified in the Query String.

*I have tried a lot, but yet unable to reach the success point.*

Just, to show you what I am doing here is the Code

> **My Code Portion**

```
/*
   Logic to generate a canvas based on some parameters goes here
*/

// Canvas to Image
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

/*
   My goal is to set this image to header of the page,
   so that when the page is hit, an image is returned,
   just like the Google Chart API thing mentioned above
*/
```

Comment: +1 for a very clearly formulated question. I can see some good-looking hits when Googling `save canvas image php` - check them out. [Save Canvas image (Post the data string to PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11385471) is a duplicate but I'm not terribly fond of the solution - an Ajax solution would be more elegant

Comment: @Pekka Thank you for the references. Please note, I dont want to save the file, I just want to use the dynamically generated image object to be sent as image Header

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "image header", can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Did you check the google URL I have mentioned??

Comment: By Returning Image Header, I mean the same, that is when you hit, the URL you are returned with an Image

Comment: Can I contact you somewhere??

Comment: It's best if you explain it here so people can think of a solution... Do you want to send the image data through an URL and get the image back? That's not going to be possible, as you will be hitting the limits for how large a GET request can be.

Comment: No, I dont want to send the image data, the image data will be created via canvas. Then, I need this data to be sent as an Image Header. Can you talk with me on skype??

Comment: Nope, sorry, I'm working and have a lot to do. I still do not understand what you mean by "image header". Can you just explain that term?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18346/discussion-between-shakir-shabbir-and-pekka)

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript variable like this:

```
 var monthly ="value to pass";
    var recent  ="value to pass";
    var imgURL="http://YOURSITEURL/FOLDER/app1?monthly="+monthly+"&recent="+recent+"&likes="+likes;
```

Or:

```
  var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src ="http://117.204.247.139:8084/myapps/app?monthly="+monthly+"&recent="+recent+"&likes="+likes;
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely sure If I understand what you want. But on the PHP side you can
generate a PNG or JPEG file with a library like GD or Imagemagick.

(http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

You can then send the data back to the client by setting the correct header, for PNG:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
ob_start();
echo $pngdata; // the binary data
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: You are right in your answer, this will send the Image as Header, but my requirement is to send an image that does not exist on the hard disk, I want to send an image that is created on the go, that is a user may provide any text and based on that text, an image is generated, I want to send this image as header

Comment: but you can do that with the GD library :)

Comment: How is the question, how will you pass a javascript variable to a PHP function